# How to create character vector of all sentences in a webpage using R

Tags: r, html, text-mining, text-analysis

I am using R to 'webscrape' a webpage and do text mining on its contents. What I need to do is get a character vector in R where each element in the vector is a sentence from the webpage. Is there a way to identify the individual sentences within an html document? Somehow detecting whatever occurs before and after periods.

I do this for getting the raw URL data

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)
url.link <- 'http://www.webpage.com'
webpage <- getURL(url.link)
webpage <- htmlParse(webpage, encoding = "UTF-8")
titles <- xpathSApply (webpage ,"//loc",xmlValue)
```

Then I extract text from each page:

```
traverse_each_page <- function(x){
tmp <- htmlParse(getURI(x))
xpathSApply(tmp, '//div[@id="mainContent"]', xmlValue)
}

pages <- sapply(titles[2:3], traverse_each_page)
```

but I get the following error and cannot proceed:

Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE) : url malformed Called from: .rs.breakOnError(TRUE)

Comment: I suggest looking at the `tm` package, the [tm webmining plugin](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm.plugin.webmining/tm.plugin.webmining.pdf) [PDF] and the `Maxent_Sent_Token_Annotator` function in the `openNLP` package.

Comment: Not all sentences end with periods, though, do they? ;)

Comment: Can you give a specific webpage for which you would like to do this?